# Retrieve response object after UI action?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

so I've created several service tests where I validate the response object, normally using the requests library or http library to send a POST request for example.

This time however I'm doing an end-to-end test.  Through the UI progressing through a workflow, one stage involves uploading a document, behind the scenes this will call a separate service, the response of which will contain some information that could be useful to me for further verification.

Is there a way to merge these?  After the UI action can I 'listen' for the response object somehow?

I do NOT wish to call the endpoint directly as I want to prove the workflow is as intended, the endpoint is verified directly in service level tests already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate `Selenium` tests with `BrowserMob Proxy` and you will be able to 'listen' for the responses using `HAR` file:
https://bmp.lightbody.net/
<sub>Java repo where the feature is implemented: https://github.com/Wikia/selenium-tests</sub>

Comment: unfortunately I can't rely on something like that in this case but it certainly would solve the problem.  I think I'm just going to accept this is a potential issue with the test